# How can open docx in Chrome rather than download

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have code to open the docx file in the browse. When it opens on IE, the Microsoft Office Word will open without saving.  However it didn't work on Edge and Chrome. When it opens at Edge or Chrome, it shows about:blank, the file is downloaded and has option to open it.
I also follow the [open docx in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939808/open-docx-in-asp-net) to use `Response.WriteFile` instead of `Response.TransmitFile` but it doesn't work.
Would someone tell me what I should do to make it work?

There is my code:

```
Response.ClearHeaders()
Response.ClearContent()
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"
Response.TransmitFile(filePath)
Response.Flush()
Response.Close()
```

Comment: I am pretty sure that this is not something you can control server-side. These things [need to be configured client-side](https://superuser.com/q/1206815/14517), and that's a good thing.

Comment: Browsers decide which file formats they're going to do special things for, or handle themselves, vs just letting you download the file and find a program yourself to deal with the file.

Comment: The only thing that tells the browser how to handle the file is the `Content-Disposition` header. Using `WriteFile` or `TransmitFile` doesn't affect that. Even then, the browser will display a file only if it can, or if a viewer plugin is available. 10 years ago, IE used ActiveX to actually start Word if it existed on the server to display a file's contents. That was very expensive, only runs on Windows *and* a major security risk, which is why no other browser does it. It wasn't uncommon for companies to disable this through Group Policy either